# Remove childnodes in mongodb java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I have a collection where it contains child nodes of contact numbers as below.

```
{"username":"abc",
"email": "xxx@xxx.com",
"contact":[
            {"number":"4763485364","type":"mobile"},
            {"number":"4535345345","type":"home"}
          ]}
```

its a repeating set and I want to know how can I remove or change the specific number in the child node based on the type using the mongodb Java driver. I was able to remove the entire element using the BasciDBObject with the find method in the collection. But I want to remove only one number ("home" type) from the child node for the specific user. Can someone show me a sample code in java how can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use $pull to remove an item from the array.

```
collection.update(new BasicDBObject("username","abc"), new BasicDBObject("$pull", new BasicDBObject("comments", new BasicDBObject("type","home"))));
```

This code will pull the element from the `comments` array that matches the criteria `type = "home"`, from the item in the collection that matches the criteria `username ="abc"`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I tried and it works. However I have a question whether i can sort the child nodes and remove the top element. Its not suitable for this question, however i have another set of values which have numeric values in child node.  is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it is. You will have to do it java though, by retrieving the list, sorting it, removing the top element and then update(if required) in the database. Can you please accept the answer if it solved your problem?